# Reading excel files in a streaming fashion in spark 2.0.0

Tags: excel, apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-excel

I have a set of Excel format files which needs to be read from Spark(2.0.0) as and when an Excel file is loaded into a local directory. Scala version used here is 2.11.8.

I've tried using `readstream` method of SparkSession, but I'm not able to read in a streaming way. I'm able to read Excel files statically as:

```
val df = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel").option("sheetName", "Data").option("useHeader", "true").load("Sample.xlsx")
```

Is there any other way of reading excel files in streaming way from a local directory?

Any answers would be helpful.

Thanks

---

Changes done:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir","file:///D:/pooja").appName("Spark SQL Example").getOrCreate()
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.streaming.schemaInference", true)
import spark.implicits._  
val dataFrame = spark.readStream.format("csv").option("inferSchema",true).option("header", true).load("file:///D:/pooja/sample.csv")
dataFrame.writeStream.format("console").start()
dataFrame.show()
```

---

Updated code:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("Spark SQL Example").getOrCreate()
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.streaming.schemaInference", true)
import spark.implicits._  
val df = spark.readStream.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel").option("header", true).load("file:///filepath/*.xlsx")
df.writeStream.format("memory").queryName("tab").start().awaitTermination()
val res = spark.sql("select * from tab")
res.show()
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Data source com.crealytics.spark.excel does not support streamed reading
```

Can anyone help me resolve this issue.

Comment: still a valid question; couldn't figure out how to readStream Excel files. Only works for CSVs for me

Answer (score 0):

For a streaming DataFrame you have to provide Schema and currently, DataStreamReader does not support `option("inferSchema", true|false)`. You can set SQLConf setting `spark.sql.streaming.schemaInference`, which needs to be set at session level.

You can refer [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16924)

Comment: ,Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: But I need to read excel files in a directory as and when it is appearing in the directory.Is there any way using textFileStream or some other method.

Comment: After setting the above SQLConf property you can do something like this

val dataFrame = spark.readStream.format("csv").option("inferSchema","true").option("header","true").load("/path/to/your/folder/*.csv")

you can replace the extension of csv with your excel file

Comment: You can set SQLConf property like this : 

spark.sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.streaming.schemaInference","true")

where spark is your spark session in REPL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I've tried with the above changes,but facing new issues as:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)

Comment: I'm trying to read files from my D drive in my system.Is this error due to that?

Comment: Can you please post what you tried with the above changes?